# Failed to subscribe to multiple topics(connection gets interupted)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt, packet, mosquitto

I wanted to get the message from mutiple topics but the connection gets interupted as when i recieve the message and publish the message, byitself it publishes the same message which i had published in the before rather than my own message to the client. Btw this code is to find the missing packet that is being recieved by the client and it publishes back the missing packet in the format(1,first_packet - lastpacket). the published message that is sent to the client is sent back to the subscriber without any acknoledgement

can anyone figure out why this code gets interupted as when i try to subscribe to multiple topic and this code get exited when it gets the same published message

```
//importing heading files
var mqtt = require('mqtt'); // to import mqtt
const mongoose = require("mongoose"); // to import mongoose
const Data = require('./models/data'); // to import the models data
const TopicT = require("./models/topict"); 
const Topic = require("./models/topic");
const Packets = require("./models/packets");
const TopicS = require("./models/topics");
const TopicK = require("./models/topick");

var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

//packet module
temp_sum = 0
new_sum = 0

const packetfind = require('./packetfind');
var count = 0;
alphas = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
mongoose
  // .connect("mongodb+srv://blackfrog:blackfrog@cluster0.pxmd1.mongodb.net/emvolio", {
  .connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/eagleeye", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Database is Connected");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

options = {
  username: "000000",
  password: "password",
  clean: true
};
//Mqtt Connections
var client = mqtt.connect("mqtt://localhost:1883", options);
// var client = mqtt.connect("mqtt://15.207.2.27:1883", options);
client.on("connect", function () {
  console.log("mqtt connected");
});

client.on('message', async function (topic, message, packet) {
  console.log("message is " + message);
  console.log("topic is " + topic);
  var topic_arr = topic.split('/');
  var fullPacket = message.toString().split(';');
  var message_arr = fullPacket[0].toString().split(',');
  var netConArr = fullPacket.shift();
  netConArr = [];
  if (fullPacket) {
    for (let i = 0; i <= fullPacket.length; i++) {
      if (fullPacket[i]) {
        var net = fullPacket[i].toString().split(','); 
        netConArr.push({ "network": net[0], "mcc": net[1], "mnc": net[2], "loc": net[3], "cellid": net[4] });
      }
    }
  }

  var re = /:/gi;
  var con = /(\w+)\s(\w+)/;
  var interMedDt = message_arr[1].replace(re, " ");
  interMedDt = interMedDt.replace(con, "$2 $1");
  var datTimes = new Date(interMedDt);
  await datTimes.setHours((message_arr[2].split()[0]).split(':')[0]);
  await datTimes.setMinutes((message_arr[2].split()[0]).split(':')[1]);
  await datTimes.setSeconds((message_arr[2].split()[0]).split(':')[2]);
  var timeZone;
  if (message_arr[22]) {
    timeZone = Number(15 * message_arr[22]);
  } else {
    timeZone = Number(15 * 22);
  }
  var latitude;
  var longitude;

  //console.log(timeZone,message_arr[22], datTimes)
  datTimes = await new Date(datTimes.setMinutes(datTimes.getMinutes() - timeZone));
  //console.log(topic_arr, message_arr);
  const id = await Data.find({ id: topic_arr[0] }).then((data) => {

    return data;
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
  //console.log("data was successfully recived");
  //console.log("id:",id);

  //Receiving Data
  var count_data = 0;
  switch (topic_arr[1]) {
    case 'T':
      const new_packet = await {
        lastupdatedTime: new Date(),
        packet_number: message_arr[0],
        dateTime: new Date(datTimes),
        date: message_arr[1],
        time: message_arr[2],
        temp1: message_arr[3],
        temp2: message_arr[4],
        temp3: message_arr[5],
        battery_charge: message_arr[6],
        latitude: message_arr[7],
        longitude: message_arr[8],
        setpoint: message_arr[9],
        lid_open: message_arr[10],
        battery_temp: message_arr[11],
        hs_heatsink: message_arr[12],
        cs_heatsink: message_arr[13],
        ntc_main_board: message_arr[14],
        pid_value: message_arr[15],
        average_voltage: message_arr[16],
        charging_indicator: message_arr[17],
        fan_lock: message_arr[18],
        network_status: message_arr[19],
        password: message_arr[20],
        average_temp: message_arr[21],
        time_zone: message_arr[22],
        ntc_voltage_board_temp1: message_arr[23],
        ntc_voltage_board_temp2: message_arr[24],
        ntc_charging_board_temp1: message_arr[25],
        ntc_charging_board_temp2: message_arr[26],
        warning_status: message_arr[27],
        imei_number: message_arr[28],
        networkConnection: netConArr,
      };
      // packets
      // console.log(new_packet)
      var loc = await TopicT.find(
        { id: ObjectId(id[0]._id) },
        { last_latitude: 1, last_longitude: 1 }
      );
      console.log(loc);
      if (Number(message_arr[7]) && Number(message_arr[8])) {
        latitude = message_arr[7];
        longitude = message_arr[8];
      } else {
        latitude = loc[0].last_latitude;
        longitude = loc[0].last_longitude;
      }
      if (new Date(new_packet.lastupdatedTime) >= new Date(new_packet.dateTime)) {
        await TopicT.updateOne({ id: ObjectId(id[0]._id) }, { last_latitude: latitude, last_longitude: longitude, packets: new_packet })
          .then((data) => console.log(data))
          .then((data) => console.log("data was successfully added to the topic collection"))
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));

        new_packet.id = ObjectId(id[0]._id);  
        const packets = new Packets(new_packet);
        //console.log("Fullpacket", new_packet);
        //test case1: first packet\
        

        if (count == 0) {
          temp_packet = new_packet.packet_number;
        }
        else {
          great_check = 0
          count_temp = 0
          count_packet = 0
          // for (i =0; i<temp_packet.length; i+=1)
          // {
          //   if (temp_packet[i] == "0")
          //   {
          //     count_temp += 1;

          //   }
          //   if (new_packet.packet_number[i] == "0")
          //   {
          //     count_packet += 1;
          //   }
          // }
          // if count_temp > 
         
          var first = parseInt(temp_packet, 36);
          var end = parseInt(new_packet.packet_number, 36);
            if (first > end ) 
            {
            break;
          }
          
         
          
          if ((alphas.indexOf(new_packet.packet_number[4]) != (alphas.indexOf(temp_packet[4]) + 1)) && (great_check == 0)) {
            console.log("packet  INDEXis "+new_packet.packet_number);
            console.log("temp  INDEX is "+temp_packet);
            value = packetfind.packetfind(new_packet.packet_number, temp_packet);
            console.log("value is " +value)
            temp_packet = new_packet.packet_number;
            console.log("temp_packet", temp_packet, "value[1]", value[1], "value[2]", value[2],);

              if (value[0] == 1) {
                var interval = setInterval(function () {
                  let pub_topic = topic_arr[0] + '/R';
                  let pubmessage = 1 + ',' + value[1] + '-' + value[2] + ';';
                  console. log("pub", pubmessage);
                  let pub_options = { qos: 0, retain: false };
                  client.publish(pub_topic, pubmessage, pub_options, function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                      console.log("An error occurred during publish");
                    } else {
                      console.log("Published successfully");
                      value.splice(0, value.length);
                    }
                  });
                }, 10000);
                setTimeout(function () {
                  clearInterval(interval);
                }, 10000);
                break;
              }          
          }
          else{
            if (great_check == 0)
            {
              temp_packet = new_packet.packet_number;
            }
          }
        }
        count = count + 1;
        //console.log("temp packet number", temp_packet) ;
        await packets.save()
          .then((data) => console.log(data))
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        break;
      }

      else {
        break;
      }A
    case 'K':
      const k_packet = await {
        lastupdatedTime: new Date(),
        packet_number: message_arr[0],
        date: message_arr[1],
        time: message_arr[2],
        vacc_recipient_name: message_arr[3],
        recipient_id: message_arr[4],
        recipient_dob: message_arr[5],
        vacc_name: message_arr[6],
        manufacture_date: message_arr[7],
        vacc_batch: message_arr[8],
        remarks: message_arr[9],
        variant: message_arr[10],

      };
      k_packet.id = ObjectId(id[0]._id);
      const packetK = new TopicK(k_packet);

      k_packet.save()
        .then((data) => console.log(data))
        .then((data) => console.log("data was successfully added to the topicK collection"))

        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      break;
    case 'S':
      const s_packet = new TopicS({
        id: id[0]._id,
        packet_number: message_arr[0],
        imei: message_arr[1],
        lid_opening: message_arr[2],
      });
      s_packet.save()
        .then((data) => console.log(data))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
});

client.on("error", function (error) {
  console.log("Can't connect" + error);
  process.exit(1);
});
client.subscribe("#", { qos: 1 });
```

Comment: Please turn your example into a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (i.e. remove as much code as you can to simplify it). I'd suggest starting with a minimal `'message'` handler and then re-adding code until the issue occurs (its likely that you will then spot the issue yourself).

Comment: Also what do the mosquitto logs show when you get disconnected? Are you running with ACLs?

Comment: the  logs shows that there is not message and gets interupted since it republishes the value which i had published as client which is" 1,start-end" which is not the message that the client should recieve as the gets same published message back